# Quantifying active screen time with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, accessibility

I'm trying to improve my ergonomics setup. I've got dual monitors, and trying to figure out how they should be placed (e.g., one directly in front and the other off to the side, vs both in front offset at equal angles).

Is there an application that can be run in the background to profile which part of my workspace is active, which would help inform monitor placement?

Comment: You want to *time* it or make it visible?

Comment: Time it; it could be as simple as reporting what percent of time I'm on my left monitor vs my right monitor. Even better, it could generate a 'heat map' showing where on my workspace sees the most activity.

Comment: What is your DE / window manager?

Comment: Usually GNOME, but could switch to KDE for a few days to get the profiling data.